# ANDROID::GET ID(R.drawable.image) value of the image in a imageview

Tags: android, database, imageview

I would like to store image ID's of the images in ImageView into database....then use these IDs as to change the images in ImageViews dynamically...

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Perhaps include some more detail, or some of the code you are working with.

Comment: k...let me make it clear..
User will select few images of his choice den i need to store dose images(i mean their ids to database)...And afterwards retrieve those ids frm d database and load d corresponding images in d imageview.....

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much simpler than you think it is.

The trick is to use `Tag`, so after you set image to the `ImageView`, set a tag with value of the `Drawable` id, afterward you can retrieve the id by getting tag.

```
public void setImageTag(ImageView imageView, int resId) {
    imageView.setImage.... <--- set your image
    imageView.setTag(int);
}

public int getImageTag(ImageView imageView) {
    return (int)imageView.getTag();
}
```

Comment: but this demand to set Tag of each and every imageview with its corresponding image...
Is dere ny alternate method by which i can get id of d image ina imageview Dynamically..

Comment: I don't think you want to store the actual int id's of the views. I am not certain, but I don't believe you have any guarantee that the id's for each view will remain unchanged from install to install. So if you are storing those and acting based upon them you may get some funky results after a new version of your app is installed.

Comment: Yea...i agree with ur point..But right now am planning for app which to store image's r.drawable ids  rather than d image itself..i feel its rather convenient for ma app.